# eslint object-shorthand error with variable passed in

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have the following function that is setting up a select2 plugin, which needs selects to stay open if they are multiple but closed if they are not:

```js
function setUpSelects($selects, closeOnSelect) {
  $selects.each((i, item) => {
    const $item = $(item);

    $item.select2({
      closeOnSelect: closeOnSelect,  // <-- error on this line
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      placeholder: $item.data('placeholder') || $item.attr('placeholder'),
    });
  });
}

setUpSelects($('select:not([multiple])'), false);
setUpSelects($('select[multiple]'), true);
```

However, when I try to run this code, the eslint checker is giving me an error (on the line shown above) of:

> error  Expected property shorthand  object-shorthand

I have done a search and read the docs but it doesn't show how you are meant to use a variable and the unaccepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898616/identifying-gulp-eslint-error-reason) seems to think it may be a bug in eslint (although I have found no evidence to support that)

Is there a way to make this work or should I just disable the rule for that line?

Comment: In ES6, you can/should use `{foobar}` instead of `{foobar: foobar}`.

Comment: Have you tried using object shorthand notation like `{ closeOnSelect, minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity, ... }`?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could just leave the argument blank if it is called the same thing - I was just going to comment I noticed the Ininity variable worked

Comment: Weird, now you have told me that this page makes a whole lot more sense: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand.  They don't explain it very well in the first example

Comment: I wonder why it is I only get downvoted when I ask a js question, even though it has enough code to repeat my problem and a clear problem statement.  Not all of us are js gurus

Comment: I'm assuming you're using some sort of pre-packaged rulebook that goes with eslint (otherwise the rule would have been there because you've explicitly set it). I use the airbnb guide which happens to use this rule as well but their rationale is generally more helpful than what you'd find in the eslint pages [here's the description](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#es6-object-concise).

Comment: @apokryfos, that is much more helpful - at least there is an explanation to go with that as well as an example.  I read the eslint one over and over and didn't get what the difference was as it didn't have an explanation of what it was changing, I guess the main confusion was that it showed a couple of examples rather than just one example and the way to correct it also confused me because it went from each property on a their own line to all on a single one

Answer (score 185, accepted):

An [excerpt](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand#rule-details) from eslint regarding the issue:

> **Require Object Literal Shorthand Syntax (object-shorthand) - Rule Details**
>
> This rule enforces the use of the shorthand syntax. This applies to
>   all methods (including generators) defined in object literals and any
>   properties defined where the key name matches name of the assigned
>   variable.

Change

```
closeOnSelect: closeOnSelect
```

to just

```
closeOnSelect
```

Answer (score 15):

This [rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand) checks that object literal shorthand [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax) is used, e.g `{a, b}` instead of `{a: a, b: b}`. The rule is configurable, see [options](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand#options) for more details.

Despite this shorthand syntax is convenient, in some cases you may not want to force it usage. You can disable the check in your config:

```
// .eslintrc.json

{
  "rules": {
    // Disables the rule. You can just remove it,
    // if it is not enabled by a parent config.
    "object-shorthand": 0
  }
}
```

In case of **TSLint** there is a different [option](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/object-literal-shorthand/):

```
// tslint.json

{
  "rules": {
    // Disables the rule. You can just remove it,
    // if it is not enabled by a parent config.
    "object-literal-shorthand": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that you may need to restart your web-server for the updated ESLint settings to have been applied.

Answer (score -1):

Wants to define Object with keys and can't use any. Try this.

interface Map {
[key: string]: string | undefined
}

```
const HUMAN_MAP: Map = {
  draft: "Draft",
}

export const human = (str: string) => HUMAN_MAP[str] || str
```